# Powershell command SetUser for a List

Tags: powershell, email

I am using the following command for about 100 users. I would like to put the email addresses in a list and have it run through them.

```
Set-User -Identity name@company.org -LinkedMasterAccount $null
```

Trying this

```
Import-Module activedirectory
$session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri 
http://servername/powershell -Authentication Kerberos - 
Credential $mycredentials
Import-PSSession $session
$list=Get-Content "C:\Email.txt"
ForEach ($user in $list) {Set-User -Identity $user-LinkedMasterAccount $null}
```

This file exists and it looks to be interating through it - I get an error for each listed below

```
A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '$null'.
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-User], 
ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Set-User
+ PSComputerName        : servername.com
```

Comment: Look at the `Get-Content` cmdlet and `foreach` loops then post here if you have specific problems with your code.

Comment: See code above - getting a cannot bind argument to parameter path

Comment: Please edit your question and post the actual error. Does c:\email.txt actually exist?

Comment: First, it looks like you are missing a space. So this: `Set-User -Identity $user-LinkedMasterAccount $null` Should be this: `Set-User -Identity $user -LinkedMasterAccount $null`

Comment: and that was it! Thank you for your help and encouragement

Comment: EBGreen - how do I "Give you credit" for this?

Comment: Don't worry about it. Give it to Vivek.

Answer (score 0):

Put your emails in a `txt` file and loop through each of them like -

```
Get-Content \\PathToYourTextFile\File.txt | % { Set-User -Identity $_ -LinkedMasterAccount $null }
```